# Grails domain property nullable - true by default?

Tags: grails, grails-3.3

Regarding setting a domain class property to be nullable, as described here: https://docs.grails.org/3.3.10/ref/Constraints/nullable.html

Is there a way to make "nullable equals true" to be the default for all properties in all my Grails domain classes? As opposed to the default for nullable being false.

As an additional note, I also have the property 
`grails.databinding.convertEmptyStringsToNull = false` 
in my `application.yml` file.

I'm on Grails 3.3.10.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define default constraints for all domain classes in `grails-app/conf/application.groovy`.

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
    '*'(nullable: true)
}
```

See the [Sharing Constraints](http://docs.grails.org/3.3.10/guide/validation.html#sharingConstraints) section of the docs for more details.